# Programmatically remove/hide view during initialization

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a few stacked views, for one I would like to do some checks and in certain cases remove the View from the stack.
The view should be removed/hidden during initialization, before the user gets to see the view.

The views are registered using the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point and stacked using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` (`relationship="stack"`).

I tried the following but the view is still visible:

```
@Override
public void init(IViewSite site) throws PartInitException {
    site.getPage().hideView((IViewPart) site.getPart());
}
```

I guess there is a way using `IPartListener` or `IPartListener2` but I would prefer some nicer way.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this that doesn't result in the view appearing at least briefly. Some views just display a message rather than their normal contents.